# systemd RequiresMountsFor multiline syntax

Tags: systemd

I know that this is a valid systemd unit configuration file syntax:

```
[Unit]
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/foo /mnt/bar
...
```

Recently, I've seen a multiline variant of the above:

```
[Unit]
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/foo
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/bar
...
```

**Are these two syntaxes semantically equivalent?**

I checked the RequiresMountsFor option in the systemd.unit manpage, which explicitly states: *"Takes a space-separated list of absolute paths."* Also there's a hint on similarities with Requires and After options. The Requires option's documentation explicitly states that the single-line and multi-line syntaxes are equivalent (for the Requires option): *"This option may be specified more than once or multiple space-separated units may be specified in one option in which case requirement dependencies for all listed names will be created."* So I'd guess that the same applies to RequiresMountsFor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it’s equivalent indeed:

```
# tee /run/systemd/system/serverfault-1085820.service >/dev/null << 'EOF'
[Unit]
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/foo
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/bar
[Service]
ExecStart=echo hi
EOF
# systemctl daemon-reload
# SYSTEMD_PAGER=cat systemctl show -p RequiresMountsFor serverfault-1085820.service 
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/bar /mnt/foo
```

This should probably be documented better in the manpage; it’s *not* true for all directives, as systemd.syntax(7) points out:

> Various settings are allowed to be specified more than once, in which case the interpretation depends on the setting. Often, multiple settings form a list, and setting to an empty value "resets", which means that previous assignments are ignored. When this is allowed, it is mentioned in the description of the setting.